# Summing time fields over 24 hours in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a Power Query in excel linked to another file. This file has a time column. I understand that M language will not sum above 24 hours automatically without some work as it uses a datetime reference hence if I import a time of 25 hours it reverts back 2 hours to 1 hour...

In the 3rd column along in my image below using the second row as a reference, this is actually supposed to read 47:47:38. How can I get the instances where the value is above 24 hours to show the true hours?

I have tried using duration.hours(#hours()) this also does not work for some reason.

The same data from the source excel file is below also

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Power Query doesn't have custom formats for how it displays data. If you have it read your data as a Duration instead of a DateTime it will display as [d].hh.mm.ss format, but still not with the total hours. Ultimately though this doesn't really matter because even when your data is formatted to display total hours in Excel, it's really being stored internally as days+hours+minutes+seconds. So how it displays in Power Query doesn't matter, as you can just use the hour formatting wherever you output the data to.

Now if you need to use the hours for a calculation between something that isn't another Duration, you can extract the hours by doing

```
Duration.Days([Your Hours]) * 24 + Duration.Hours([Your Hours])
```

Or now that I look at it, there is also a TotalHours function that gives you the hours plus mm:ss as a fractional amount of that

```
Duration.TotalHours([Your Hours])
```

Comment: Unfortunately the solution yields an Expression.Error. We cannot convert  the value #datetime(1899, 12, 31, 10, 17, 23) to type Duration. Details: Value:=12/31/1899 10:17:23 AM Type=Type

Comment: You would need to have converted your values to a Duration instead of a DateTime for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Power BI doesn't handle this case very gracefully. A solution could be to convert the duration to a number to make it additive (so you can perform calculations and aggregations) and when you need to visualize it, to convert it to the desired format (HH:MM:SS).

`Duration` and `Time` are often confused. When such Excel files are read, the type of the column usually is `DateTime`, and date 1899-12-31 is added to the "time" part. You can change the data type of the column to be Decimal Number, but the "zero point" in Excel unfortunately is one day off (1899-12-30), so you need to subtract 1 from the result to get the actual "number of days" of the duration (i.e. 0.25 means 06:00:00).

So you must perform some conversion of the data. I would make a new column in the model to get the duration in the lowest granularity that I need (seconds in your example). In Power Query Editor add a custom column to calculate the duration in seconds (where `Column1` is the name of the original duration column):

```
Duration in seconds = Duration.TotalSeconds([Column1] - #datetime(1899, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0))
```

[image]

Make sure the data type of this column is Whole Number (change it if necessary). Here `9144` seconds are calculated as `2 * 3600 + 32 * 60 + 24`, or `02:32:24`. Now you can calculate a sum on this column to get total duration in seconds for example. But when you visualize this column, don't do it directly, but make a measure to convert the data to the desired format. It could me made like this:

```
Measure Duration = 
    VAR duration_in_seconds = SUM(Sheet1[Duration in seconds])
    VAR hours = ROUNDDOWN ( duration_in_seconds / 3600; 0 )
    VAR minutes = ROUNDDOWN ( MOD ( duration_in_seconds; 3600 ) / 60; 0 )
    VAR seconds = INT ( MOD ( duration_in_seconds; 60 ) )
    RETURN hours & ":" & FORMAT(minutes; "00") & ":" & FORMAT(seconds; "00")
```

`duration_in_seconds` variable hold the total duration in seconds of the data in the context. From it we are calculating `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` and constructing a string to represent the duration in the desired format. [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax) is used to make sure there is a leading zero in case minutes or seconds are less than 10.

Here is how all three columns looks like when visualized:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with all the solution above is that they will not generate an output that is a duration in the format `hhh:mm`.

When you format it as a string the sorting on this column will not work. I am currently also struggling with this issue.

It's a pity that they [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/duration-totext?source=docs) the formatting option on `Duration.ToText`:

```
Duration.ToText(duration as nullable duration, optional format as nullable text) as nullable text
```